# export data between two dates into a csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export

I have `index.html.erb` looks so:
[image]

when the user press 'apply' button, I want to export all the date from my table into a csv file (and save it).

**I defined in my `reports_controller.rb` the next line:**

```
require 'csv'
```

**and I passed all the parameters by ajax into the controller (to the function update).**

now:

start_day = **the start day that the user selected**

.

.

.

end_year = **the end year that the user selected**

**in my update function, I tried to create the csv file. In order to search in my table between two dates, I created two variables: start_date and end_date.**

start_date = YYYY-MM-DD (while: YYYY is the start_year, MM is the start_month and DD is the start_day).

end_date is similar to start_date (but with: end_year, end_month and end_day)

**so this is my update function:**

```
def update
    @start_day = params[:start_day]
    @start_month = params[:start_month]
    @start_year = params[:start_year]

    @end_day = params[:end_day]
    @end_month = params[:end_month]
    @end_year = params[:end_year]

    # the format of start_date and end_date will be: "YYYY-MM-DD"
    @start_date = @start_year + "-" + @start_month + "-" + @start_day
    @end_date = @end_year + "-" + @end_month + "-" + @end_day

    # get all the transactions between start_date to end_date
    @transactions = BillingTransaction.find(:all, :conditions =>["date(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ? ", @start_date, @end_date])

    # create the csv file
    csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
        # insert the headers
        csv << ["transaction_type", "payment_method"]
        # run all over the transactions
        @transactions.each do |user|
            # each of transactions is inserted into the csv file
            csv << [BillingTransaction.transaction_type, BillingTransaction.payment_method]
        end
    end         

    # save it as 'BillingTransaction.csv'
    send_data csv_string,
    :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=BillingTransaction.csv" 
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it should not be in the `update` method, because it breaks the RESTful principle. You could create a custom method which can be called `transactions`, or something like that.

Because it is not modifying anything and will produce a CSV therefore it can work as a GET method. Of course you'll need to modify the routes to make this method visible.

It's also a good idea to create a `Date` object from the parameters, like:

```
@start_date = Date.new(@start_year.to_i, @start_month.to_i, @start_day.to_i)
@end_date = Date.new(@end_year.to_i, @end_month.to_i, @end_day.to_i)
```

instead of building strings.

And in the `each` block you should add the actual value:

```
@transactions.each do |transaction|
  # each of transactions is inserted into the csv file
  csv << [transaction.transaction_type, transaction.payment_method]
end
```

And finally you don't need to use instance variables (prefixed with `@` sign) for those variables which you do not want to use in your views.

So here nothing needs to be prefixed with `@`,

Comment: thank you!!! I make all you suggested me and made the method transactions visible, by:  resources :reports do
    collection do
      get :tarnsactions
    end
  end

and change the ajax method to be: $.ajax({
       url: '/reports/transactions',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {start_day: $(".start_day").attr("value"), start_month: $(".start_month").attr("value"), start_year: $(".start_year").attr("value"), end_day: $(".end_day").attr("value"), end_month: $(".end_month").attr("value"), end_year: $(".end_year").attr("value")}
     });

what's now? I pressed the 'apply' and nothing happens.

Comment: Check the logs whether the request has been made by the browser or not.